# Verificar se duas teclas foram pressionadas ao mesmo tempo python

Tags: python, teclado

Olá pessoal estou usando o python e o modulo pynput.keyboard para verificar teclas pressionas até ai tudo okay, mas eu gostaria de saber quando duas teclas foram pressionadas ao mesmo tempo: exemplo Shift + L ou qualquer outra combinação.

o código atual é:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key

def press(key):
  print(key)

with Listener(on_press=press, on_release=release, on_pressed=pressed) as listener:
  listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Você teria de ter uma lista, fora das funções "press" e "release". Quando um keydown for registrado por "press", adiciona à lista (se já não estiver lá). Quando um keyup for registrado por "release", remove da lista.

Aí basta, no epílogo da função "press", verificar se alguma combinação de teclas está presente na lista.